# Защита аутентификации

Tags: сессия, браузер, защита, аутентификация

К примеру есть любая соц. сеть, она же хранит залогиненых пользователей с помощью токена сессии? Т.е. где-то в локальном хранилище браузера храниться ключ, который отправляется на сервер, сервер смотрит в свою БД есть ли такая сессия, и в зави симости от наличия отправляет либо залогиненую html либо нет.

Но, разве это безопасно? Нужно всего лишь узнать этот ключ и можно на своем браузере зайти на чужую страницу, разве нет других, более безопасных решений?

Можно проверять ip, и другие штуки, но тот же youtube при смене ip не выкидывает, а загружает аккаунт (конечно при одной и той же сессии).

Comment: Ну и каким именно образом вы собрались «всего лишь узнать этот ключ»? :)

Comment: @andreymal это уже другой вопрос, ведь можно спокойно с компьютера в учебном заведении посмотреть это, потом дома делать что угодно.

Comment: @kitsoRik где вы собрались это "спокойно посмотреть"?

Comment: Ну так вы просто не сохраняйте свою сессию на компьютере в учебном заведении, специально для этого в браузерах изобрели режим инкогнито

Comment: @andreymal да не то я имел в виду, к примеру есть сайт для прохождения тестов, где учитель зашел под своей учетной записью что бы студенты проходили тесты, мы же можем потом дома делать с его записью что угодно.

Comment: @kitsoRik учитель вас пускает к своему собственному компьютеру просто так? Ну значит он сам виноват, надо было хотя бы пароль на компьютере ставить

Comment: Действительно, когда https/tls ещё не вошли так плотно в обиход,как сейчас, достаточно было "на лету" похитить куку пользователя, чтобы перехватить его сессию. Не нужно было вводить логин и пароль. 
Сейчас на всех более/менее крупных соц.сетях уже давно активировали асимметричное шифрование, и сделать такую операцию стало затруднительно. Теперь для этого необходимо либо выполнить MitM с расшифровкой сессии, либо завладеть машиной пользователя и куками на ней, раньше чем истечёт срок их действия.

Comment: @StanislavPechezerov да, это я понимаю, так выходит получить доступ по конкретному токену (просто скопировав, сфотографировав) можно получить очень ценную информацию. Да возможно это редкость (я так делал только один раз в жизни, и то для своей страницы, так как нужно было подтверджения с телефона, а он сел, но именно тогда меня это и начало напрягать, потратил меньше 2 минут), но не стоит списывать это счетов.

Comment: По сути кроме ip адреса нет ничего, что нельзя было бы подделать (потому что все остальное рождается на компьютере пользователя и может быть сэмулированно програмно, будь то mac адреса, серийники дисков и т.п.). А ip может часто меняться. И тогда пользователю будет не удобно постоянно подтверждать сессию (вводя пароль, который то же можно перехватить хоть раз получив доступ п компу и установив кейлогер)

Comment: И кстати, получив один раз доступ к компу можно поставить на него проксю и выходить в сеть под ip пользователя. так что он то же не надежен. Единственной защитой был бы usb токен с ключем ассиметричного шифрования (они используются для электронной подписи). Но они редко используются и у обычных пользователей их нет. Правда при желании можно сделать программу, которая по сети получит запрос, подпишет его локальным токеном и отправит злоумышленнику, так что опять облом. И того приходим к тому, что без физической защиты своего устройства все равно 100% гарантий дать нельзя

Comment: @Mike можно, нужно каждый раз логиниться по новой без сохранения сессий, :D. К примеру, на работе у меня был сообственный юзер, и всегда когда я уходил от компютера на несколько минут я блокировал его.

Comment: Совсем без сохранения сессий невозможно, протокол http к сожалению разрывает соединение после каждого запроса, а следовательно сессию на уровне tcp поддерживать невозможно. Коротко живущие сессии запросто, но они просто не удобны пользователю, он ленив и не захочет постоянно вводить пароль. Значит он сохранит его в браузере, что от хранения сессии ничем уже не отличаеться

Comment: @Mike сессию - это я имел ввиду через ключ который храниться где-то в БД на сервере

Comment: Ну вот про них я и говорю, что без них никак нельзя, потому что каждое обновление страницы - новый запрос для сервера, ничем не связанный с предыдущими, если нет кук

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я все свои деньги храню в кошельке. Но разве это безопасно? Ведь любой, кто возьмет мой кошелек сможет расплачиваться моими деньгами.

Итого, если вас беспокоит безопасность, у вас есть два варианта:

1. После завершения работы с сайтом нажимать Logout
2. Не давать работать посторонним людям под своей учеткой в ОС

Там, где это критично (например, личный кабинет в банке) сессия автоматически закрывается через 10-20 минут неактивности.

Comment: да, это основы защиты информации, я хотел узнать мысли других людей, возможно есть нечто лучше чем просто ключ хранящийся в куках. Спасибо.

Comment: @kitsoRik. Есть, OpenID и аналогичные сервисы. Но насколько это лучше или хуже - решать вам